# Set const string value match function name

Tags: c#, constants, declaration

There are functions that call other function via name (for example: [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)).

Normally, I use it like this:

```
void Start()
{
    Invoke("SelfDestroy", 2);
}

public void CancelDestroy()
{
    CancelInvoke("SelfDestroy");
}

void SelfDestroy()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

But I'm a lazy guy so I don't want to type one string multiple times (I may make typo mistake), so I do it like this:

```
const string SELF_DESTROY_METHOD = "SelfDestroy";

void Start()
{
    Invoke(SELF_DESTROY_METHOD, 2);
}

public void CancelDestroy()
{
    CancelInvoke(SELF_DESTROY_METHOD);
}

void SelfDestroy()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

But it still doesn't satisfy me, I want the constant string `SELF_DESTROY_METHOD` programmatically matches the method `SelfDestroy`, so if I change the name of the method `SelfDestroy`, the value of constant string `SELF_DESTROY_METHOD` is automatically updated accordingly. Is it possible in C#?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me. If you were _really_ lazy, you would not call it by its string name (with all the possible spelling errors) but call it by its function name and use your IDE's autocomplete functionality to help you write faster and error-free.

Comment: I think [`nameof(SelfDestroy)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof) is what you're looking for. But as Uwe said - your code looks a bit strange. Your code should look like `const string SELF_DESTROY_METHOD = nameof(SelfDestroy);`

Comment: @SebastianSchumann: great ideal, but unfortunately, I got the error: `Feature 'nameof operator' is not available in C# 4.  Please use language version 6 or greater.` (I'm using Unity), but I'm glad there is a solution.

Comment: @UweKeim - But the `Invoke` method requires me to call it via its string name.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann - I can solve the error now, I just need to change Scripting Runtime Version to .NET 4.x https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html Thanks. So nameof is the solution, please post the answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sebastian Schumann's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231019/set-const-string-value-match-function-name/56234227#comment99081625_56231019), the solution is [nameof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/nameof).
The code should be

```
const string SELF_DESTROY_METHOD = nameof(SelfDestroy);

void Start()
{
    Invoke(SELF_DESTROY_METHOD, 2);
}

public void CancelDestroy()
{
    CancelInvoke(SELF_DESTROY_METHOD);
}

void SelfDestroy()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Note: I used Unity and had my Scripting Runtime Version `.NET 3.5`, so I got the error `Feature 'nameof operator' is not available in C# 4. Please use language version 6 or greater.`, so I upgrade the Scripting Runtime Version to `.NET 4.x` and it works, check [Scripting Runtime manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingRuntimeUpgrade.html) for more info.